# How do I stop popunders in Firefox that resist ad blockers?

Tags: popups, adblock

I find that recently there are a lot of popunders that are not getting blocked by standard popup blockers like Ad-Block and Poper Blocker.

I suspect that these are implemented as CSS overlays that are Javascript created. In other words a script is running and dynamically generating the popunder. It is not part of the page HTML, so it is not getting filtered.

How can I block them?

An example are the ads on boston.com

Comment: Some are impossible to block and still view the site.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to install and use "uBlock origin" (less work) or uMatrix (more work) and specifically block those scripts. NoScript should also work. Be aware though that uMatrix and NoScript need continously tending to.